# Possible Piracy - Is it off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Am I right to flag a question as off-topic if the questioner is asking for a method of circumventing the Terms of Service of a web service even if the service provider does not rigorously enforce the clause that specifically prevents?

Comment: Web services are off topic anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Possible piracy is one of many considerations within the sphere of what I would call 'License Management'. Not OT from my point of view.

Comment: A question about "License Management" is a lot different than "How to I steal this?" ;)

Comment: Absolutely agree! But a question on using a mass deployed script to audit licenses to find differences against what was paid would be legitimate. And possible piracy related. And license management!

Comment: Auditing for piracy is auditing, not piracy. ;)   In this question specifically the OP is saying that the "questioner is asking for a method of circumventing the Terms of Service of a web service".  You shouldn't have to circumvent a ToS to perform an audit or do license management, and asking *how* to circumvent the ToS is (essentially/similar to) asking for help in stealing/pirating.

Comment: Perhaps "related to piracy" is too broad/general of a way to think of it. Sure, you can mention piracy in passing, and it can by involved in *why* you're asking your question, but as soon as the question becomes "How do I pirate" then it's bad news. :)

Comment: Not necessarily Techie007. You would need to clarify and be careful but it's entirely possible they are asking how to circumvent a security control in order to build a reporting mechanism re. Licensing or application usage monitoring. Or they might need assistance pushing the limits of a said control for QA purpose. Not everybody examining the limits of a security control is looking to steal. The primary evidence we have is thin and I don't think we can assume some is trying to pirate.

Comment: Pardon my phone typos!

Comment: So if I was to say "I stole your car to test your security", you'd be ok with me stealing your car? ;)  Anyhow I'm sure you'll agree it's too broad/vague/gray a topic to really nail down, and really needs specific context.  In the case of a ToS on a web service, if you're trying to circumvent it, you're being bad.   If you're hired by said web service to test the security of it, then you're not an end-user/customer, and not beholden to the ToS.  Again we'd need more specific context.

Comment: In general, here on SU, people asking to circumvent security put in place by others is generally (if not always) frowned upon (i.e.: we get a butt-load of "How can I circumvent my school's/country's/company's network policies/filter?").

Comment: See [Handling questions clearly trying to break some kind of policy, TOS, etc](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/533/handling-questions-clearly-trying-to-break-some-kind-of-policy-tos-etc), where the accepted answer is "yes, flag it!" :)